# Why do we divide by n when solving for the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound here?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fisher-information, point-estimation

"Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid Bernoulli(1,$p$), with $p$ unknown. Find the CRLB for the variances of unbiased estimators of $p$."

With pdf $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$, the derivative of the log function is $\frac{x}{p}-\frac{1-x}{1-p}$

The second derivative is $-\frac{x}{p^2}-\frac{1-x}{(1-p)^2}$.

With $E[X]=p$ for a bernoulli, taking the expected value of the second derivative yields

$-\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{1-p}=-\frac{1}{p(1-p)}$

so the Fisher information $I(p)=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}$ and the CRLB is $p(1-p)$

Except the answer is $\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$. I thought when solving this, I was already solving for a single sample $X_i$, so why am I dividing by the number of samples $n$?

I can't wrap my head around how the initial problem wording is saying anything different from what I solved for though. This has been something that has shown up in more than 1 problem for me, sometimes with the answer dividing by $n$ and other times just leaving it as is. Guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Until you wrote "dividing by the number of samples $n,$" your question had nothing to do with the samples: the pdf to which you refer is for a *single* one of the $X_i.$  The solution to your problem, then, lies in writing down a correct expression for the likelihood of the *entire sample.*

Comment: Isn't that what I want though (clearly not but). Where in the question statement is it asking for the pdf to be the pdf of the entire sample, because I can only read it as asking for a single sample?

Comment: The PDF is for a single *observation.*  The CRLB applies to the *likelihood,* which expresses the density for the entire *sample.*  You haven't examined the likelihood yet.

Comment: I see now. I knew the answer involved using the pdf of all samples $p^{\sum x}(1-p)^{n-\sum x}$, but didn't see why. This clears it up; likelihood is something determined off everything, not a single sample (as is intuitive in hindsight); thank you.